# Entity Framework Core 7.0 grabs an unconfigured database to execute

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

My app was working very fine, and I am not sure when this problem started. I have just upgraded VS2022 to 17.6 and it may or may not be related to it.

When I run my app, everything loads fine, which means the correct database in the connection string is used, until I execute an API request to insert a record into the database. I then get an error saying:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint “SalesOrders_SalesOrderDetails”. The conflict occurred in database “StoreTestRMDB”, table “dbo.SalesOrders”, column ‘OrderID’.

What is strange in this message is that the database in the connection string is not `StoreTestRMDB`, although it is one of the databases on my instance.

So where is EF Core getting this database name from? I searched my entire solution for any mention of that database name, and nothing was found. This application was working fine before, so EF started generating this error when I upgraded to VS 17.5 or 17.6, I am not sure which one of the two.

Please find below the details of the error text that is thrown. If you look at error, you will notice that the database that is accessed is the `StoreTestRMDB`, which is a database in my database instance. But this is the wrong database and it is not configured anywhere in my solution, not even in the configuration files. The actual database it is supposed to access is the `StoreRMDB`. Why is this happening?:

> [01:35:54 Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update
> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type ‘WinRetailerDAL.DataModels.SalesContext’.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint “SalesOrders_SalesOrderDetails”. The conflict occurred in database “StoreTestRMDB”, table “dbo.SalesOrders”, column ‘SalesOrderID’.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.NextResultAsyncExecute(Task task, Object state)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeAsyncCall[T](SqlDataReaderBaseAsyncCallContext1 context)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ClientConnectionId:9b183d4c-2222-41da-bfb8-d664333b60b4
> Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func4 operation, Func4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.

I tried searching for the database that EF Core tries to execute against everywhere in the solution to see where it is getting that database name from.

I also tried to see how EF Core reads in the database it executes against, but nothing was found. I have no idea why and how EF Core is behaving like this.

There is something I think I should add to the initial post that could prove to be useful:

1. I was using the StoreTestRMDB to generate scripts to migrate data from an old database to a new one using SSMS (SQL Management Studio) and this database was used for testing. I did not, at any time, use this database in my VS project. I only used it with SSMS.
2. This error only occurs during debugging. It does not occur when I publish the project to another machine, probably because the StoreTestRMDB does not exist in other machines. But I would like to know why and how EF is getting the StoreTestRMDB from?

Comment: Please show the configuration used to create your EF Context, show your config files, show how you read the config files etc. In short, we need a [mcve].

Comment: If you are pulling connection strings from a configuration file, check your local directories for any instance of the .config or .json files where these settings reside. You may have a rogue copy in a /bin folder being used where the execution path is now different from earlier runs. (Did your Solution Config selection change from Debug etc.?) If in doubt sometimes I find with .Net Core and VS2022 that you just need to wipe the /bin and /obj folders... (Though not usually for config issues)

Comment: It would be great if you can include your code snippet as well which causing this error that would be easier to assist you.

Comment: @Mason, there is nothing special about the configuration. Just the standard like so:
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConn": "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress2016;Initial Catalog=StoreRMDB;Integrated Security=True" 
  },

And I use DI to read the config files like is shown below (these are actual code snippets from my project):
   public SalesOrderController(SalesContext context, IConfigHelper configHelper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _configHelper = configHelper;
        }

Comment: @Steve Py, I tried to as you suggested and deleted the bin and the obj folders and tried again. I still get the same error. I did, however, find a .config folder in the debug directory and I opened it and found a dotnet-tools.json file and the below are the contents of that file, although I am not sure what it does. It points to an older version of EF:

{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-ef": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "commands": [
        "dotnet-ef"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, the code that is causing the error is the standard insert code in the POST method of a controller as shown below (This is the actual code snippet from my project):

        _context.SalesOrders.Add(sOrder);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
The error happens at the _context.SaveChangesAsync() line.

Comment: Thanks for your response and it would be great if you could include the details code snippet within your question, in order to investigate or reproduce.